# Print data in html/JS from a different html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not a very experienced programmer, but I'm working on a project (Chatbot).
I want to ready data from the user such as ID#. And I want to compare this ID# with another one in a different html file.

For example:
User typed: ID07

The script should look for this ID in the other html file(IDs.html)
and print the data under that ID.

Something like the below:

```
//ID07
<div>
    <p>Name: Nick <p>
    <p>Age: 30 <p>
    <p>Country: USA <p> 
</div>

//ID08
<div>
    <p>Name: Darryl <p>
    <p>Age: 45 <p>
    <p>Country: France <p>  
</div>
```

So how would I do something similar in html/JS ??

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? Where is that file stored? Are you going to store data in HTML like that?

Comment: I was trying to read data from an Excel, but I dk if that's possible. So what's the best way to store data in and read from it by ID#?

Comment: From JavaScript, it is possible, but you definitely don't want to do that. Why don't you use JSON? I think you can export JSON from Excel.

Comment: Can I add it to my current code or I need to start over?

Comment: "add it to my current code" Add what?